# Why does my domain not show up in Google anymore?

Tags: seo, google

So I have had a website since about 2006. It's http://earlz.biz.tm . Recently I've noticed that no results will show up for it in google. I do have a secondary domain(that I plan on getting rid of) pointing to it but I don't understand why google would suddenly not show my site.

I believe it was showing up a few months ago and my website is hardly ever down, like one or two days I believe has been the most it's been down in a row in this time period.

Is there something wrong with my DNS or other configuration that would make google not index me?

For reference I've tried:

[earlz.biz.tm](http://www.google.com/#sclient=psy&hl=en&site=&source=hp&q=earlz.biz.tm&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&pbx=1&fp=9bef8cda26d1a6ec)

[site:earlz.biz.tm](http://www.google.com/#sclient=psy&hl=en&q=site%3aearlz.biz.tm&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&pbx=1&fp=9bef8cda26d1a6ec)

and the heading from my site ["Earlz.biz.tm -- The reasoning is bacon"](http://www.google.com/#sclient=psy&hl=en&site=&source=hp&q=%22Earlz.biz.tm+--+The+reasoning+is+bacon+%22&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&pbx=1&fp=9bef8cda26d1a6ec)

A few show up with the therusticstone.com domain(the one I plan to point somewhere else) but none show up directly linking to earlz.biz.tm.

**Update**

Ok, I got my site verified and such and it says there are zero crawls and all that. When going to the Lab's feature "Fetch As Google Bot" I found the problem. I tried to simply do http://earlz.biz.tm and it said "DNS not found." I don't see any obvious problems with my DNS records though and I haven't changed them in months

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with your DNS record, but biz.tm's whois service is really messed up; just answers with an ad.  You may want to use one of the free/paid DNS tests if you really want to validate.

Comment: @Jason I've decided it's long time for me to get an actual .com domain anyway so this question is irrelevant. I figure it's a good time to switch URLs since I don't have any thing to lose

Answer (score 1):

You have two domains (therusticstone.com and earlz.biz.tm) pointing to the same content.  Google has decided that one of them is authoritative.  If you want to "fix" this, you'll need to look into implementing something (301 redirects, canonical meta tag, etc) to tell google that the second domain is actually the canonical version.

Answer (score 0):

well you're not no-following or disallowing in robots.txt so I'm going to go ahead and assume that you're site is probably flagged for may be spam.

But your best bet is to try and resubmit your site to google and link to your site from other sites and wait a couple days. Also if you think there might be some spammy or blackhat stuff in your site, remove it. I know you don't.

Also use google's own webmaster tools, verify your site.

It should tell you what is up.

good luck
use these links below.
to submit http://www.google.com/addurl/?continue=/addurl

google webmaster tools http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/

Comment: I verified my site. Read the update to my question

Comment: best bet is to refresh. reset your dns. leave it empty for some time then put it up again. good luck

Comment: hey on your source there is an xml tag above the DOCTYPE.. is it necessary?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the `biz.tm` domain has been flagged by Google for spam or malware, reducing its search engine ranking. If that site gives away free subdomains then a different subdomain could have been flagged, thus knocking out the entire domain.

As far as I can tell, `.biz.tm` is not a top level domain, only `.tm` is (which incidentally is the country code for Turkmenistan). Something similar happened with the `gb.com` domain - many people bought subdomains thinking they were legitimate TLDs and the entire domain got wiped out of Google.

Although your exact problem may be something a little different to this, I would suggest switching to your dotcom domain; you will almost certainly rank much better. You could even buy earlz.com or earlzbiz.com, if available, so it's easier for users to remember the new domain.

Comment: I have had a .biz.tm domain for like 5 years now. And .biz.tm isn't wiped out by google, just search .biz.tm and you get other sites(mostly spam and porn though)

Comment: Exactly: Google has marked biz.tm as a spam domain and thus does not return it in meaningful searches.

Comment: no, I mean when you search .biz.tm you will pull up OTHER *.biz.tm results, but not mine.